# how many times a parameter was call

Tags: php

I'n just learning PHP by myself, and I have a question, hope you will be able to help.

In fist style

```
<?php
class Fist_style
{
    function method_1()
    {
        global $a;
        return $a + 1; 
    }

    function method_2()
    {
        global $a;
        return $a - 1;
    }

    function method_3()
    {
        $call_1 = $this->method_1();
        $call_2 = $this->method_2();
    }

    // In this case, how many times $a was called?
}
```

In second style

```
<?php
class Second_style
{
    function method_1($a)
    {
        return $a + 1; 
    }

    function method_2($a)
    {
        return $a - 1;
    }

    function method_3()
    {
        global $a;

        //I will call both method_1 and method_2
        $call_1 = $this->method_1($a);
        $call_2 = $this->method_2($a);

        //............
    }

    // In this case, how many times $a was called
}
?>
```

The questions are inside my code, and what style will better when develop?

Comment: Why not make `$a` a property of the class, and use `$this->a`? Usage of the `global` keyword isn't recommended.

Comment: This smells like a homework/test question... Could you tell us what are the answers to those questions based on your current knowledge and why? If you are right people here will confirm your answers, and if you are mistaken they can explain why the answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using globals is very often a recipe for disaster - as many people with experience will be happy to tell you.

The normal way of having state in a class is declaring a class property:

```
<?
class MyClass
{
    public $a;

    function __construct($valueForA) {
        $this->a = $valueForA;
    }

    function increment()
    {
       $this->a += 1; 
    }

    function decrement()
    {
       $this->a -= 1; 
    }

    function plusminus()
    {
        $this->increment();
        $this->decrement();
    }
}
```

Which can be used like so:

```
$anInstance = new MyClass(10); // sets a to 10 by calling the __construct method
$anInstance->increment();
echo($anInstance->a); // 11
$anInstance->decrement();
echo($anInstance->a); // 10
```

Read more about oop in PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

As for the question in your code, the `$a` is not a method, so it can't be *called*.

Also, `return $a -1;` does not change the global `$a` (not sure if this was the intention).

*Edit*:

If you have a function increment like

```
function increment ($var) {
    $var = $var - 1;
    return $var;
}
```

then the `$var` is passed in as a value - if you passed in a `5`, php only cares about `5`, not the name. Example:

```
$a = 5;
$incremented = increment($a);
echo($a); // echoes 5;
echo($incremented); //echoes 6
```

I would suggest reading up on [scoping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in php.

Comment: in your code, does it has difirent if we put i parameter like `increment($a)`, `decrement($a`), then i declare ` $a = this->a;` inside `plusinus()` , and pass two method with their parametes (`$a`)?